# why output is showing NaN while finding the discriminant in quadratic equation

Tags: javascript

```
function validate() {
    let text1 = document.getElementById("a").value;
    let text2 = document.getElementById("b").value;
    let text3 = document.getElementById("c").value;
    let result;
    let discriminant = parseFloat(text2) * parseFloat(text2) - 4 * parseFloat(text1) * parseFloat(text3);
    document.write("discrimant is " + discriminant)

}
```

Comment: Please show your html too

Comment: One of your values is not a number definitely. check very well. You may also like to trim the values before parsing to float eg document.getElementById("a").value.trim()

Answer (score 0):

If your html tag **isn't** `input`, then you need to use `textContent` instead of `value`.

Based on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-value-attribute/#:%7E:text=The%20value%20attribute%20in%20HTML,progress%3E%20and%20.)

> value attribute can be used with the following elements
> `<input>`, `<button>`, `<meter>`, `<li>`, `<option>` `<progress>` and `<param>`.

```js
validate();
function validate() {
    let text1 = document.getElementById("a").textContent;
    let text2 = document.getElementById("b").textContent;
    let text3 = document.getElementById("c").textContent;
    let discriminant = parseFloat(text2) * parseFloat(text2) - 4 * parseFloat(text1) * parseFloat(text3);
    document.write("discrimant is " + discriminant)
}
```

```html
<div id="a">1</div>
<div id="b">2</div>
<div id="c">3</div>
```